# Microsoft OneNote remove phantom "currently being edited" indicators

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

After editing a OneNote page from my browser, sometimes I get phantom "currently being edited" indicators that indicate that I'm still editing a page after I close the tab. They look like a green line with my initials to the right of them at the top. Is there any way to remove these? And is there any way to prevent this in the future?

[Visible editor 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5BHX.png)

[Visible editor 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXijV.png)

Comment: You should be able to post images now.